# What does "they both can't be selected" mean?

Tags: meaning, word-order, negation, logic, quantifiers

The sentence "**They both can't be selected**", does that mean *(1) None of them can be selected* or (2) *They both can't make it at the same time, only one of them can* ?

If I, for example, want to mean the second sentence, do I have to change the words around?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regarding usage of "both"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/334814/regarding-usage-of-both)

Comment: Best to rephrase entirely. 'Neither can be selected' or 'It is not possible to select both of them'.